# How to access sprite sheet as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new to Action script 3, please tell me how to access each image inside sprite sheet to the class As3 or any other reference project also kindly provide me.

Also step by step process to access these images inside my custom class.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well... what IDE you use? Flash? Flash Develop? You could either use Flash where you have your animations already, or you can create an swc and call it with ActionScript. Google it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Flash CS6. Please tell me any reference for this.

Comment: How to do it in action script and also goggle it but no solutions solved it. please help me i need to submit the project by tomorrow.

Comment: What do you already have?

Comment: I have an sprite sheet which contains all the images of hero in one png file. Now i need to know how to call each image in sprite sheet and how to access in my class as3                                    AS I was new to actionscript kindly tell me the syntax and method to use

Comment: http://gotoandlearn.com/ -  Search for sprite sheets.  There's multiple video tutorials on using spritesheets.  The spritesheets and blitting tutorials are probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of work involved when it comes to sprite sheets.
There are frameworks and libraries that help you do this.

It also depends on what technique you use to display things (regular DisplayObjects, blitting, starling, ...)

You should have the sprite sheet as a BitmapData object, by either loading it with a Loader or embedding it. (how this works is not within the scope of your question, I assume)

From there, the code does what you would normally do with such a sheet: cut it into pieces.
To do this you create a second BitmapData object, this will be your character or whatever.
This is the BitmapData that you actually display. Do this for example with the help of an Bitmap object.

What you do now is to use copyPixels() to copy portions of your sprite sheet to your character BitmapData. This methods takes a rectangle (among other things) as a parameter that specifies what portion of the source BitmapData (that's the sprite sheet) should be copied.

What you now have to do is change what sections are copied depending on what you want to achieve.
Maybe there's a sequence in your sheet, so you would have to move the rectangle object in order to copy different "frames" of the animation.

As mentioned, there are other ways to display this data, but in essence it all boils down to copying pixels from the sheet and throwing them at something that an display them.
And the copyPixels() method does that.

Comment: I am trying to display the regular display objects in which each image in the sprite sheet should be called and also is there any samples please send and i were trying this for long time

Answer (score 0):

Try using Starling, instead classic Flash

look this link:

http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/movie_clips

```
// Embed the Atlas XML
[Embed(source="atlas.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
public static const AtlasXml:Class;

// Embed the Atlas Texture:
[Embed(source="atlas.png")]
public static const AtlasTexture:Class;

// create atlas
var texture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmap(new AtlasTexture());
var xml:XML = XML(new AtlasXml());
var atlas:TextureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(texture, xml);

// create movie clip
var movie:MovieClip = new MovieClip(atlas.getTextures("flight_"), 10);
movie.loop = false; // default: true
addChild(movie);

// control playback
movie.play();
movie.pause();
movie.stop();

// important: add movie to juggler
Starling.juggler.add(movie);
```

Comment: I am trying to display the regular display objects in which each image in the sprite sheet should be called and also is there any samples please send and i were trying this for long time